# Spark driver synchronous execution

Tags: apache-spark, asynchronous, driver, execution, synchronous

From my understanding, Spark uses **lazy evaluation** to perform the actual computation. A transformation chain is executed on the executors only when an action is called on that chain. All of this happens on the **driver**, which is a single thread process. By default, the order of actions declared in the code is always preserved.

My question is: Does the driver perform a **synchronous** call by waiting the triggered execution completes before proceeding with the next code instruction? In other terms: are driver scheduling instructions blocking?

Here is an example with just Spark API calls:

```scala
spark
    .read
    .schema(mySchema)
    .json(myFilePath)
    .withColumn("a", col("b") * 2)
    .filter(col("c") > 300)
    .count()

spark
    .read
    .schema(mySchema2)
    .json(myFilePath2)
    .filter(col("d") < 100)
    .count()
```

Here, two actions are scheduled and executed, by default, ensuring the same order as they're declared.

Another example with a Scala statement:

```scala
val df1 = spark
    .read
    .schema(mySchema)
    .json(myFilePath)
    .withColumn("a", col("b") * 2)
    .filter(col("c") > 300)

// no execution happened until here

val df1Count = df1.count()    // "count" action triggers the execution

println(s"df1 contains ${df1Count} rows.").  // rows are logged correctly
```

Given the fact that `df1Count` contains the result of an execution on a cluster, does the driver **wait** to complete the execution before calling the `println` statement?

Am I missing something? I'd like to know more about it, so some official documentation or blog post would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the DRIVER is responsible for the generation of the Logical and Physical Plan.

So the driver is "waiting" for an `action` (here, `count`), to create logicial plan, and send work to executors.

Then, your scala code is waiting for executor responses end execute other lines.

BTW, this is possible to execute code in parrallal: see https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/boosting-apache-spark-application-by-running-multiple-parallel-jobs-25d13ee7d2a6:

```
object ParallelProcessing {

  val queries: List[(String, String)] = List(
    ("SELECT * FROM ABC", "output1"), 
    ("SELECT * FROM XYZ", "output2")
  )

  // Just use parallel collection instead of futures, that's it
  queries.par foreach { 
    case (query, path) =>
      val dataPath = s"${pathPrefix}/{path}"
      executeAndSave(query, dataPath)
  }
  
  def executeAndSave(query: String, dataPath: String)(implicit context: Context): Unit = {
    println(s"$query starts")
    context.spark.sql(query).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(dataPath)
    println(s"$query completes")
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, both the `withColumn` and `filter` operations are *transformations* so they are evaluated lazily. The `count` operation is an *action* that triggers the execution of those transformations. Unlike transformations, actions are executed synchronously.

Actions and transformations are discussed in the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) (this part of the documentation discusses RDDs but the same applies to dataframes).

Comment: The distinction between transformation and action is clear. The question is about whether the driver waits until an action is successfully computed/completed on the cluster before moving to the next instruction defined in the user code or not.

Comment: But I think the documentation can somehow give the answer : “The Spark RDD API also exposes asynchronous versions of some actions, like foreachAsync for foreach, which immediately return a FutureAction to the caller **instead of blocking on completion of the action**. This can be used to manage or wait for the asynchronous execution of the action.”